# Android OTA update fail when increased the system.img size

Tags: updates, stock-android, ota-update, aosp, development

I am working on IMX6Q with **Android 7** for **OTA update**. Current **system.img** size **499 MB** with this OTA update work. I increased this due to compilantion error. If **system.img is above 499 MB ota update fail**.

Comment: eMMC specifications?

Answer (score 0):

Removed webview application from build. webview application is the default one in Android AOSP build. But, It takes 40MB.